# Serilog multiple global loggers

Tags: .net-core, logging, serilog

I have a **net core 7.0** application with **Serilog** library for logging.
I've defined different log levels. For example, those errors which are **fatal**, **critical** will be reported using the **slack sink**, so the developers will receive the error in their slack.
Then we have the daily operations from users that need to be persisted in a database. In my case I'm using the **MSSqlServer sink**, so I can save them in a table.
Finally I'm using **MSSqlServer sink** again for logging users that enter and exit the system. In this case I need to persist this in a different table within the same database.

Here's what I did.

I create some extension methods so I can wire them up with the **WebApplicationBuilder**.

```
public static Serilog.ILogger CreateAuditLogger(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
public static Serilog.ILogger CreateSessionLogger(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
public static Serilog.ILogger CreateLoggerSlack(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
```

Then I load them from **program.cs**

The thing is that **Log.Logger is a global shared logger**, so calling these methods will override the global logger with the last extension method that was invoked.

for instance, the code below will create the logger *(I ommited the details about provided sinks...)*

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger()
```

Is there a way to register global loggers just the way it is the *the globally shared logger* ? I would like to have one of it for **slack**, another for **MSSqlServer sessions** and **MSSqlServer audits**

I've been reading something about sublogger, but I think It'll be quite complex to add all these conditions to filter the correct logging in each case.

##### Reference

https://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by chaining the loggers like this

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc =>
        lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("Type", "A1"))
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: _connectionString,
        sinkOptions: sinkOptionsAudit,
        columnOptions: columnOptionsAudit))

   .WriteTo.Logger(lc =>
        lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("Type", "B2"))
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: _connectionString,
        sinkOptions: sinkOptionsSession,
        columnOptions: columnOptionsSession))

    .WriteTo.Conditional(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error
        || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal,
        wt => wt.Slack(new SlackSinkOptions
        {
            WebHookUrl = "slackapi/messages",
            PropertyOverrideList = new HashSet<OverridableProperties>()
            {
                OverridableProperties.CustomIcon,
                OverridableProperties.CustomUserName
            }
        }))
        .CreateLogger();
```

I encapsulate this in an extension method in **program.cs**.
Then I created a static class called **LoggerHelper** with some methods.

```
public static void EmitFatalSlack(string stackTrace)
{
    Log.Fatal($"{stackTrace}");
}
public static void EmitCriticalSlack(string stackTrace)
{
    Log.Error($"{stackTrace}");
}
public static void EmitAudit()
{
    Log.Information("some message");
}
```

So whenever I need to log messages to a database or slack I use those methods.